# Exporting to XML using VBA - Header Corruption

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I admit that what I am doing is perhaps a bit of a bodge job and that there may be more technically neat ways of doing this which I haven't thought of.

I have an excel sheet creating an XML structure by brutish methods.

Basically the cells going down column A are (as text):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ReportingInfo Version="1.0" CreationDate="2017-03-14T11:02:49">
<RecordInfo>
<FilingType>INIT</FilingType>
</RecordInfo>
```

I then have a bit of vba code to export the sheet as an xml file:

```
Public Sub ExportToXML2()

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet
Dim i As String
i = Date
i = Replace(i, "/", "")

Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")     'Sheet to export as XML
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count) Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Projects\XML_Report_" & i & ".xml", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False


Workbooks.Open "C:\Projects\XML_Report_" & i & ".xml"

End Sub
```

Which creates an XML file which looks like this:

```
"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?>"
"<ReportingInfo State=""GB"" Version=""1.0"" CreationDate=""2017-03-14T11:02:49"">"
<RecordInfo>
<FilingType>INIT</FilingType>
</RecordInfo>
```

Any ideas why the extra quotation marks are showing?

Many thanks.

Comment: perhaps FileFormat:=xlXMLSpreadsheet would do the job?

Comment: Unfortunately that triggers excel to insert much more XML. Really what I want excel to treat this as is a txt file formatted with XML markup that then gets saved with xml as the file extension. If that works...

Comment: How are your cells formatted in your workbook. Perhaps the issue is that they are formatted as text, and therefore get quotation marks in the export, as to recognize the values as text.

Comment: Changing the format from text to general doesn't change the output. What is weird is how it only impacts the first two lines. Is that as it relates to an XML header?

Comment: If your sheet will always be formatted the same way and only the value of FillingType changes, you can use MSXML to create the XML file and tailor it specifically rather than exporting the whole sheet and losing control over the outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save as CSV or Text, Excel will parse the text and enclose anything containing quotes, in quotes. This is your problem. To avoid this, create your XML by saving as a textstream (preferably unicode), as here.

Data in Output, a1:a6:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ReportingInfo Version="1.0" CreationDate="2017-03-14T11:02:49">
<RecordInfo>
<FilingType>INIT</FilingType>
</RecordInfo>
</ReportingInfo>
```

Code:

```
Public Sub ExportToXML2()
    Dim fso As Object, txt As Object
    Dim lines As Long
    Dim i As String

    i = Date
    i = Replace(i, "/", "")

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txt = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Projects\XML_Report_" & i & ".xml", True)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output") 'Sheet to export as XML
        For lines = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            txt.WriteLine (.Cells(lines, 1))
        Next
    End With
    txt.Close
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Projects\XML_Report_" & i & ".xml"
End Sub
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ReportingInfo Version="1.0" CreationDate="2017-03-14T11:02:49">
<RecordInfo>
<FilingType>INIT</FilingType>
</RecordInfo>
</ReportingInfo>
```

Open xml in Excel:

```
/ReportingInfo      
/@CreationDate  /@Version   /RecordInfo/FilingType
14/03/17 11:02  1   INIT
```

Comment: You're a champion! I'd twigged that was the issue but didn't know how to prevent it.